# Is it possible to dynamically style Mapbox markers differently (svg fill color) based on information stored in my Rails db?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, mapbox

I have a Hotel model in my Rails db with name (string), address (string), longitude (float), latitude (float), and rating (float). I then used Mapbox-gl to create a map and added the below code to my controller (code section). I am trying to store 'rating' from my rails db in marker somehow so I can dynamically change the market color based on the rating of the hotel.

From reading the mapbox-gl documentation and examples, I configured the init_mapbox.js file correctly to load the base map with all the markers from my db (based on their lat and lng). Yet, I can't seem to access rating in the file. I was specifically trying to add a HTML div for each marker which would then have a certain CSS class based on the rating in my rails db.

My most seemingly most promising approach came from reading the docs...but it does not work.

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/custom-markers-gl-js/#style-markers

I based my below code on this:

```
    // add markers to map
    geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {

      // create a HTML element for each feature
      var el = document.createElement('div');
      el.className = 'marker';

      // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
      new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
        .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
        .addTo(map);
    });
```

### from HotelController

```
    @hotels = Hotel.all
        @marked_hotels = @hotels.where.not(latitude: nil, longitude: nil)

        @markers = @marked_hotels.map do |hotel|
          {
            lat: hotel.latitude,
            lng: hotel.longitude,
            infoWindow: render_to_string(partial: "info_window", locals: { 
            hotel: hotel }),
            rating: hotel.rating
          }
```

### from init_mapbox.js

```
const addMarkersToMap = (map, markers) => {
  markers.forEach((marker) => {
    //
    const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup().setHTML(marker.infoWindow);
    // 
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    if (marker.rating >= 7) {
      element.className = 'marker-good';
    } else {
      element.className = 'marker-bad';
    }
    // my original try^^

    new mapboxgl.Marker()
      .setLngLat([ marker.lng, marker.lat ])
      .setPopup(popup)
      .addTo(map);
    // element coloring logic
  });
};
```

```
from _map.scss
---

    .marker-good {
      fill: green !important;
    }

    .marker-bad {
      fill: red !important;
    }
```

My JS does not seem to have any effect on the SVG fill for the markets and the only message from the console is "This page appears to be missing CSS declarations for Mapbox GL JS". I guess this is because it may be clashing with the pre-loaded mapbox-gl.css file.

Anyway, I am very new to programming and trying to learn with this project so -- thank you!

Comment: Use `element.classList.add('marker-good')` instead of replacing the default `marker` class altogether. Also have you ensured that you have included the mapbox-gl.css CSS file?

Comment: No, I though that installing mapbox-gl through yarn installed the CSS file for you? I will do this now.